# How to sum value for data dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have this datatable:

```
date, sentiment, price
2015-09-05, 1, 200
2015-09-05, 2, 200
2015-09-06, 1, 300
```

I would like to get a new datatable with the sum of the sentiment per day, keeping the daily price

I tried to do this:

```
new_dt <- dt%>%
  select(date, sentiment, price)%>%
  filter(date > "2015-09-05" & date <"2015-09-06")
  group_by(date)
```

expected output:

```
date, sentiment, price
2015-09-05, 3, 200
2015-09-06, 1, 300
```

Comment: After the `group_by(date) %>% summarise(price = first(price), sentiment = sum(sentiment))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the summarise() function to get summary statistics:

```r
new_dt <- dt%>%
  select(date, sentiment, price)%>%
  filter(date > "2015-09-05" & date <"2015-09-06")
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(sentiment=sum(sentiment),price=sum(price))
```

For price, you could use max(), min() etc depending on what you want.